# android sdk android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I tried to use FileProvider in my apk and got an error 
"FileProvider cannot be resolved".

According to the official documentation of FileProvider
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

I added import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

as a result I got one more error "import android.support cannot be resolved"
After some googling I found that I need android-support-v4.jar and it should be in /sdk/extras/android/support/v4/

But, I don't have .../sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

I tried to get extras by sdk Manager
cd android-sdks/tools 
./android sdk 
But it has not downloaded sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar

So, here is twwo questions
1. In which way my code (with FileProvider) should be built? 
2. What had happened with android-support-v4.jar?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or something else?

Comment: no, I use scripts (javac .....) for build

Answer (score 2):

Add below dependency to build.gradle file.

```
dependencies{
     //......
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Is it any way to overcome the error without using gradle (android studio) because right now I use scripts for building? I don't use eclipse or studio.

Comment: I'm using AIDE and I don't use gradle, how do I add the support library?